# Uninstalled chocolatey package and can't reinstall

Tags: powershell-5.0, chocolatey, tex-live

I installed texlive using chocolatey but forgot to pass in `--params`. I uninstalled the package using `choco uninstall texlive` and then tried to reinstall as follows:

`choco install texlive --params="'/collections:games /scheme:basic'"`

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error now:

```
ERROR: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

When I try `choco uninstall texlive` I get the exact same error. When I run `pdflatex` on the command line it doesn't seem to recognize it as a valid command.

I also found [an issue](https://github.com/naveen521kk/chocolatey-texlive/issues/2) on github which points to this problem occuring in one of their CI/CD pipelines. Futhermore in the discussion section of the main [chocolatey community page for texlive](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/texlive) a user has also reported a similar problem on their local machine.

How can I fix this to get texlive up and running again?

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the folder `c:\tools\temp-install-tl`. I think powershell was having a hard time overwriting it. Strange that this didn't get removed during the uninstall...